# Windows 7 x64 and external Web Service problem in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm running into a strange problem. I have a simple C# console app that calls an external web service referenced within my VS 2008 .NET solution. The web service is defined as a service reference, per the vendor specs. The service requires login credentials to be sent as part of the SOAP header.

Under Vista x64/XP it runs without error. I can call the web service with the credentials and get a valid response back.

However, the **exact same exe** run under **Windows 7 x64 (build 7100)** returns an HTTP error, "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (411) Length Required".

I don't have a huge amount of experience calling web services, especially under a service reference, but this problem has me baffled.

It seems like I might be able to fix the "issue" by setting the content length in the SOAP header but I don't see that exposed from the generate service proxy. Or perhaps there's a Windows 7 security setting that needs to change. I don't know.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the http request packet created on win7 is different from the one in vista/xp. Can you run [netmon](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/) to check what is the difference between requests sent from vista/xp and win7 machines? This should give the exact reason for this failure.